# redirect flask with token

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I'm new in flask, and i got confused when redirecting page.

so here is the problem, I have to redirect to 3rd party for my login page 
example:

```
@app.route('/hk/login/3rdparty', methods=['GET'])
def login_3rdparty():
  if request.method == 'GET':
    app_id = 'xxxxx'
    secret = 'xxxxx'
    data = 3rdparty.connect(app_id, secret)
  return data
```

and when i direct to the web it return like this:

```
{"url":"http://demo3.3rdparty.com/partner/code/hk?token=sometoke-sometoken-sometoken"}
```

how do i redirect from the return json? so after i direct to /hk/login/3rdparty it will redirect to the web with the token on the back of its url

sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is `data` the json that contains the URL you need?  Can you simply do `return redirect(data['url'])`?  You'd have to add `from flask import redirect` to your file for this.

Comment: yes the data contain the URL that I need. I tried your solution and it return like this

"return redirect (data['url'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers"

@coralv

Comment: Glad to hear, @SNOW.  I put up an answer with that info and some more details.  If it was helpful, please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `data` variable in your question contains the json object you need, then you can use the `redirect()` function to send your user to the address it contains.  Your answer combines both our comments, but I want to add this to make sure others can see the necessary `import` statements as well.

```
import json
from flask import redirect

@app.route('/hk/login/3rdparty')
def login_3rdparty():
    app_id = 'xxxxx'
    secret = 'xxxxx'
    raw_data = 3rdparty.connect(app_id, secret)
    data = json.loads(raw_data)
    return redirect (data['url'])
```

I don't think you even need to specify `GET` as the method if that's the only method this function uses.  Keep up the good work, SNOW.